# TicksStyle in RegionPlot

Tags: plotting

How does TicksStyle work in RegionPlot? The below does not work:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},Ticks -> {{-2, 0, 2},{-2, 0, 2}},TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegionPlot` by default gives a framed plot, so you have two options.

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{-2, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 2}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16]]
```

(`FrameTicks...` not `Ticks...`).

Or `Frame->False, Axes->True`

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, Ticks -> {{-2, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 2}}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16]]
```